# How to wait before reloading a Flask server until currently running threads end

Tags: python-3.x, flask

When running a Flask server, `app.run(debug=True)` is quite convenient to reload the server when new changes are made.

However, this approach is not recommended for a production environment and it forcibly terminates all ongoing threads.

That being said, how can I reload the server when updates are made after waiting for ongoing threads to end?